# View a type within a dll to use in a function used by that Dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interface, com

I've got a COM interface dll, and some documentation about the methods within the dll, however from what I can tell with the documentation, the method requires a custom `struct` be passed in as an `out` parameter, but the documentation doesn't provide any information about the `struct` itself.

The function I'm calling from c# is as follows:

API

```
UINT OpenRequest ([out] PHCOMS      phComs,
[in] PCHAR      pEndPointName,
[in] UINT       fBlockingMode,
[in] UINT       fOpenMode,
[in] UINT       fDataType,
[in] HINSTANCE      hInstance)
```

My issue is that `PHCOMS` is a type described in the documentation as:

> The address of a variable of type HCOMS.  The communications handle to be used by the other API calls, is returned in this variable.  If an error occurs this will be NULL.
>
> This function starts by allocating a comms handle (hComs), if
>   available, to the application. This handle is used for creating a new
>   connection object. The parameters of this function are assigned to the
>   relevant members. For this object, a pointer instance is created for
>   connecting to the interface, as well as the PC Headerpched
>   interface

I've had a look at various dll inspectors and other posts on SO but can't find anything that helps with how I can actually create a struct that's going to be validly accepted by the function.

I am also unsure if I'm misinterpreting what I need to do - is it possible that I just need to pass a standard handle through to the function or something similar? Is the PHComs type a non custom type that I just can't find info on in google?

Right now I'm attempting to call the function through c# using the DLLImport attribute over an extern function which seems to be ok except that the handle I get back is never valid, which I'm blindly (I've never done something like this before) trying to do like this

```
 [DllImport("MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern uint OpenRequest(ref SafeProcessHandle hComs, string host, uint fBlockingMode, uint fOpenMode, uint fDataType, SafeProcessHandle hInstance);

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      IntPtr h = new IntPtr();
      var handle = new SafeProcessHandle(h, true);
      uint test = 0;
      test = OpenRequest(ref handle, "Host01", 0, 0, 0, handle);
      handle.Dispose();
    }
```

Any assistance on how to setup my test properly would help too since I'm blindly guessing about the IntPtr and use of whatever Safe*Handle Classes.

**Edit**

I've changed it to be like this following Hans' comment:
As you said, there are other methods that use that handle, for example the `ConnectRequest` added below.

Any suggestion as to what the HInstance parameter refers to? I doubt it's correct that I'm just passing the same handle/IntPtr in again?
The documentation says:

> hInstance     HINSTANCE       Windows programs must pass their instance handle.

```
     [DllImport("MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern uint OpenRequest(out IntPtr hComs, string host, uint fBlockingMode, uint fOpenMode, uint fDataType, IntPtr hInstance);

     [DllImport("MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern uint ConnectRequest(IntPtr hComs, uint cTimeOut);
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        IntPtr hComs = new IntPtr();
        uint test_OpenRequest = 0;
        test_OpenRequest = OpenRequest(out hComs, "Host01", 0, 0, 0, hComs);
     }
```

**Edit 2**

```
[DllImport("WinCom32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern uint OpenRequest(out IntPtr hComs, string host, uint fBlockingMode, uint fOpenMode, uint fDataType, IntPtr hInstance);

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr hComs = new IntPtr();
            uint test_Request = 0;

            string hostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostName"];
            IntPtr hInstance = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetModules()[0]);

            test_Request = OpenRequest(out hComs, hostName, 0, 0, 1, hInstance);
Console.WriteLine("Request response value: " + test_Request.ToString());
}
```

There's a test application I can run that shows that this is supposed to work because it's able to connect to the host, so I've got to be doing something wrong.

Comment: If it is a COM DLL, would it be possible to use it via COM Interop rather than DLL Import?

Comment: Nothing to do with COM.  It is not a struct, it is a handle.  So `out IntPtr` in this case.  There should be other functions that use that handle (HCOMS instead of PHCOMS), plain `IntPtr` for them.  Creating your own SafeHandle derived class to wrap it is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your comment, I've updated my question a little from what I understand from the comment. Can you have another look as to whether I did understand or not?

Comment: The HINSTANCE is also `IntPtr`.  Highly likely that simply passing IntPtr.Zero is good enough.  If not then you probably ought to worry a bit about what it needs this for, use Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(), pass Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetModules()[0].

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks again for the help, unfortunately I can't get it to work. I've updated my question with what I'm doing currently... any chance you have any other suggestions as to what I can try?

Comment: "can't get it work" does not help me help you.  What else, what else.  Ah, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode is not correct, PCHAR requires CharSet.Ansi.  There is no indication that CallingConvention.StdCall is correct, but that bombs pretty nicely with a good diagnostic in the debugger.  Time to call the author of this DLL, send him a good repro project so he can debug his code and tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, sorry, I don't know what else I could provide that would let you help me. I get 2147549446 back from the call but that looks like some uninitialized value? I tried various combinations of changing the Char set and CallingConventions as well as hInstance and changing the fDataType between binary and character as well however I always get the same response.
The dll was written in 2004 and we've been told we'll get no assistance with it :). Thanks for all your help. I'll continue tinkering for a bit and try a c++ implementation just in case.

Comment: Finally a decent diagnostic.  2147549446 == 0x80010106 == RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE, "Cannot change thread mode after it is set".  That is a pretty naughty thing to do, but it is unhappy about the way you initialized the thread on which you run this code.  It wants you to use a GUI program to use this library.  You can put the [STAThread] attribute on your Main() method, you might get away with it.  You know you didn't if a call deadlocks or you don't get an expected event.  If it needs to be said, taking a dependency on a library that is no longer supported is not a good idea.

Comment: @HansPassant I must admit I am feeling a little more than ashamed at my assumption about that value - it never occurred to me that it would mean something specific. You've sorted me out though. It's working now. I can't say how much I appreciate your help. If you'd like to submit an answer I'll accept it. Thank you very, very much!